# Can we write marks[j]=marks[i]; inside while loop instead of marks[i+1]=marks[i];

Tags: insertion-sort

Insertion sort program in C++

```
#include"iostream"
using namespace std;
int main(){
int i,temp;
int marks[5]={12,11,13,5,6};
//this loop go through all element
//(staring from 2 to 5,
//assuming that first element is already sorted)

for(int j=1;j<5;j++){
    i=j-1;
    temp=marks[j];

    while(i>=0 && marks[i]>temp){
        marks[i+1]=marks[i];
        i--;
    }
    marks[i+1]=temp;
}

//prints all the elements..
for(int z=0;z<5;z++){
    cout<<marks[z]<<" ";
}
return 0;

}
```

can we write marks[j]=marks[i]; inside while loop instead of marks[i+1]=marks[i];

If not, why?

Comment: Sounds like a homework question, why not try it and see if it works ? and after that if you still don't understand, post a question about whatever part you do not understand

Comment: its not work,,,,

Comment: the logic seems correct ,,but why its not working,,,,

Comment: marks[i+1]=marks[i];
if we look at above program 
i+1=j

Answer (score 0):

So the answer is no - it is not the same

Using j=2 as an example, the while loop starts with i=1

The 1st iteration, marks[i+1]=marks[i], i+1 is the same as j, but then i--, so i ends up as 0 by the end of the while loop.

for the 2nd iteration in the while loop, marks[i+1]=marks[i], i+1 is NOT the same as j.